# Uniform crossover in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm, uniform, crossover

I have been able to code a `1-point crossover` as follows:

```
n_parents = length(parents);
randparents = randperm(n_parents);

parent1 = population.ind{parents(randparents(1))};
parent2 = population.ind{parents(randparents(2))};

cross_point = ceil(rand()*(size(parent1,2)-1));
child = [parent1(1:cross_point),parent2(cross_point+1:size(parent2,2))];
```

Can anyone help in converting this to a `uniform crossover` please?

Comment: What is a "uniform crossover"?

Comment: @raryeng check this out:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_(genetic_algorithm)#Uniform_crossover_and_half_uniform_crossover

Comment: Sorry, but no thanks. I won't answer a question if it requires me to go off-site and read up on something. Please don't take any offense. It has nothing to do with you personally and this is how I've always operated.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have no Matlab to check the code, but it should be something like this:

```
parent1 = population.ind{parents(randparents(1))};
parent2 = population.ind{parents(randparents(2))};

rand_vec = rand(size(parent1));
child1 = parent1;
child1(rand_vec>=0.5) = parent2(rand_vec>=0.5);
child2 = parent2;
child2(rand_vec>=0.5) = parent1(rand_vec>=0.5);
```